# Type Casting in Array

Tags: c, arrays, casting

At certain intervals the output is off by 0.1.

I have tried converting the array `cent`, that didn't work. I tried declaring extra values to store the array in, and then convert that value, that didn't do the trick either.

How can this be fixed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float amount[5];
    long dollar[5];
    long cent[5];
    float storage = 0;
    int i = 0; 

    printf("Enter five values: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%f", &amount[i]);// 2.75

        dollar[i] = (long) amount[i]; // 2.
        cent[i] = ((float)amount[i] - dollar[i]) * 100.00;//.75

        printf("$%ld.%ld.\n",dollar[i],cent[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The cast in `(float)amount[i]` is not needed as `amount[i]` already is a `float`.

Comment: right! sorry about that!

Comment: Please show us some example input and its expected and actual output.

Comment: `scanf("%ld.%ld", dollar + i, cent + i);`?

Comment: @Stargateur From which code did you get that line ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I just write it.

Comment: edit grammar and floating point notation that was making it harder for readers to understand the *error* being described

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers can't store exact representations of all numbers.

If I add the following line after the scanf:

```
printf("amount=%.8f\n", amount[i]);
```

I get this output:

```
Enter five values:
1.1
amount=1.10000002
$1.10.
1.2
amount=1.20000005
$1.20.
1.3
amount=1.29999995
$1.29.
1.4
amount=1.39999998
$1.39.
1.5
amount=1.50000000
$1.50.
```

You can see that the values are approximate.  Some are slightly higher, some slightly lower.  When you then calculate `((float)amount[i] - dollar[i]) * 100.00` the integer part is 1 less that you might expect, while the fractional part is *slightly* less than one.  Assigning this value to an integer type truncates that.

You should use the `roundf` function to round this result to the nearest integer:

```
cent[i] = roundf(((float)amount[i] - dollar[i]) * 100.00);
```

Be sure to `#include <math.h>` at the top, and link in the math library when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`cent[i] = (amount[i] * 100.00) - (dollar[i]*100);`

due to rounding errors in floating points.